# Deploying a custom php extension in any cloud

Tags: php

We are developing an application with a combination of flex, php and C++. Flex interfaces the user and c++ shared library created as php extension for DB interaction and other server activities. While PHP's responsibility is to be middle layer between flex and c++. We are planning to host this application on cloud (tried on phpclould) to make it available for customers. However, I have found out that phpcloud is not allowing configure extension directory configuration and is disabled. This is very essential as C++ component is the core of the application. Please suggest for the following:

1. Is there any way I can configure it in phpcloud?
2. Is there any other cloud that allows deploying custom php extentions?
3. Is this deployment model blocked due to security reasons?

Comment: https://getsatisfaction.com/zend_technologies/topics/customising_php_via_php_ini_where_is_it_and_phpinfo_does_not_work

Looks like extensions are disabled due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

PHPCloud has disabled custom php extensions due to security and stability reasons. Please refer to the link in the comment. Apart from that PHP too deprecating dl system call. I am currently awaiting response from appFog cloud to see if they allow it or not.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appfog-users/ZADuiFv2alA

Comment: True. We need to commission a linux VM on the cloud and configure accordingly. That is what we have done